2 black wires and 2 white wires

I'm changing a light switch to a dimmer switch. When I took off the old switch there were two black wires and two white wires as well as to ground wires. On my dimmer switch is one post for neutral and one post for hot what do I do with these extra wires?

how were they connected?  ... please edit your question and add that information ... add the picture of the connections before you started

Most switches do not connect to neutral.  Some dimmers/switches with lights/smart switches do connect to neutral for their own power(power the little light/smarts).  Add the make and model of the new dimmer to your question, but if only two brass screws, then only connect to the blacks and ground(bare) to green screw.

The switch in your hand in the pic is a 3way switch.  Does the light you are working on  have another switch that also controls it?  How the new switch gets wired depends on this answer.

"On my dimmer switch is one post for neutral and one post for hot" — That sounds very unusual, or even impossible. Why do you think that is what the two posts are for?
